# Sync progress of a action with progressBar

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to make the Progressbar show the percentage of the progress. Example:

I click in a button to start a "clean" on my computer, i want do sync the progressbar with the clean progress or vice versa.

if 50% of the files have successfully deleted then the progressbar value = 50% Understand? and show up of the progressbar how file/folder he is deleting.

Another good example: CCleaner progressbar :v

Someone can give a hand with the code?

i have the info of the files/folders.

```
    Dim info1 As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Windows\Temp")
    Dim info2 As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\Temp")
    Dim info3 As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Windows\Prefetch")
    Dim info4 As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Downloads")
```

Now i need the code to sync the clean progress with the ProgressBar.

Comment: Count all the files you are going to delete, store the number in a variable, start deleting and keep track of how many you have deleted, calculate percentage via `deleted files / total files to delete` -- I don't see why that would be so hard to figure out?

Comment: Pretty broad. But do you know the quantity `total files to delete` before you start? If not you could count them up front but that raises a question of why not just delete them at the same time? It may change an O(n) into 2x O(n) algorithm. You decide if it's valuable in your application.